# Attaching values to Options like Width and Height

Tags: image, attributes, html-select

I have Select menu. Each option switches the image displayed. I'm asking how do I translate over the each unique width and height linked to each options onto the actual displayed image. I understand the width and height are baseless as far as they're effect on an option tag but I guess Im saying is that I want a values associated and bonded to each option that come into play and effect the image when the option they are attached to is selected. Something like adding a variable like 
var c = a.getElementByTagName('class').getAttributeNode('width').value;??

I really dont know. How do I associate values with the options? Preferably there is a way without attaching a new class to every option. My code so far can only change the src.

I hope you understand the question. I explained it the best I can. Thanks for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id='select1'>
    <option value='pic_unavail' selected width='300' height='300'>-- Choose --</option>
    <outgroup label="Animals">
    <option value='pic_monkey' id='monkey' width='50' height='100'>Monkey</option>
    <option value="pic_cat" id='cat' width='100' height='200'>Cat</option>
    <option value="pic_dog" id='dog' width='200' height='250'>Dog</option>
    </outgroup>
</select>  

<img id="pic">   

<script type="text/javascript">  

document.getElementById("select1").onchange = select;

var a = document.getElementById('select1')    
var b = document.getElementById('pic');


function select() {
    b.src = this.value;
     return 
}    

 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('width');
this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('height');
```

This should give you the selected option's width and height just as you currently have them embedded in each  tag.  Hope this helps!